# Проброс реального IP внутрь Docker

Tags: nginx, docker

Nginx с хоста проксирует на nginx в контейнере.

В конфиге "хостового" nginx:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:12345;
    proxy_set_header Host      $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

В конфиге того, что в контейнере: `real_ip_header X-Real-IP;`.

У обоих включены логи в разные файлы.
В логах хостового nginx показывается мой IP, а в логах "контейнерного" - докеровский 172.30...

При этом внутренний nginx проксирует на контейнер с php-fpm. Внутри вывожу полученные заголовки и там есть "X-Real-Ip", а в нём вполне себе мой изначальный IP. То есть нужный заголовок приходит.

Как заставить nginx в докере писать в лог реальный IP?
И должен ли он его туда вообще писать или он внутренний $remote_addr не меняет никогда?

Comment: А директива set_real_ip_from в контейнере есть?

Comment: @AlexeyTen нет.

Comment: Ну так надо написать